# Python function that takes the name of another Python function as an argument

Tags: python, function, arguments

I would like to define a general function that calls another python function. I wrote the general function that takes the path to another python function and the name of another python function as arguments.

```py
import sys
def general_function(path, func):
    sys.path.insert(0, path)
    import func
```

However, when I ran the general function (saved in /MY/PATH/general_function.py), I received the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/MY/PATH/general_function.py", line 4
    import func
           ^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'func'
```

How can I fix this? I tried `import *` but it did not work either. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: If the func is not in your `site-package` folder of your python version, as numpy, matplotlib, opencv that you can install via pip, put your relative or full path to that python file

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
import os
def general_function(path, func):
    os.chdir(path)
    import func
```

Comment: I tried it but received the same error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'func'`

Comment: Can you post _exactly_ what you're running?

Comment: I run this line of code:

`python -c "from general_funciton import *; general_function(path, func)"`

Comment: you're spelling from general_funciton wrong, not sure if that's it. does from general_function import * work? and then just try that and general_function() with no arguments to see if you get an error. If it says no arguments, then its something with that specific function.

Comment: Sorry it's just a typo. I tried `general_function()` and it says `TypeError: general_function() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'path', 'func'`

Comment: ok so its the body of your function. can you post in your question how you're calling the the function? with the variables your entering for general_function()?